# rgbd_odometry: Did not receive data since 5 seconds (zed camera)

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after i install rtabmap from source when i try to run it i got this error:
[ WARN] [1516726659.614500547]: /rtabmap/rtabmap: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). If topics are not published at the same rate, you could increase "queue_size" parameter (current=10).
/rtabmap/rtabmap subscribed to (approx sync):
/rtabmap/odom,
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color,
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw,
/camera/rgb/camera_info

rostopic hz /rtabmap/odom:
subscribed to [/rtabmap/odom]
no new message
rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_rect_color
subscribed to [/camera/rgb/image_rect_color]
no new messages
rostopic hz /camera/depth/image_rect_color
WARNING: topic [/camera/depth/image_rect_color] does not appear to be published yet

so what i can do to resole this issues

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280604/rgbd_odometry:-did-not-receive-data-since-5-seconds-(zed-camera)/) by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With zed camera, the depth image topic would be something like this: `/camera/depth/depth_registered`. You may want to try Zed related instructions on this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22rtabmap_ros%2FTutorials%2FHandHeldMapping%22).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-01-24**:
@matlabbe i tried it all but i get the same issue

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-01-24**:
Try "`$ rostopic hz my/topic`" on needed topics to know if they are actually published. You can also start only the zed, then do "`$ rostopic list`" to list all available topics and copy/paste them in your question.

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-01-24**:
When i run only zed i get all topic available

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-01-24**:
... and are they published? (use `rostopic hz`)

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-01-26**:
@matlabbe i can see the image when i run
rqt_image_view

but no data published in
rostopic hz my/topic

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-01-26**:
the issue resolved just in rtabmapviz but not in rviz